# Limit of the sequence $\{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} +....+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\} -2 \sqrt n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the limit of the sequence $\{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} +....+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\} -2 \sqrt n$ if it exists.

I find that it's decreasing and if I prove that it's bounded below I can conclude that it's convergent. Please help me to prove that it's bounded below or it's unbounded.

Comment: Please try using MathJax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $t \mapsto 1/\sqrt{t}$ is monotonically decreasing, we have, for $n\geq 1$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt t }}} }  = \int_1^n {\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt t }}}  = 2\sqrt n  - 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} +....+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt n}{n}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt \frac 2n} +....+\frac{1}{\sqrt \frac nn}\Bigg)=\sqrt n\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx}$$

I'm sure you can take it from here